# Add hyperlinks in media description

Tags: media, links, html

I want to add hyperlinks in the description box of a media file in the library 
but it won't display hyperlinks for some reason. It displays text but as soon as i put a href it hides it.

i'm using the theme asteria lite

Greetings

Comment: Please share the research you have carried out so far, and what solutions you have tried.

Comment: i tried to look in firebug to see if it's maybe a css issue but i cannot find it .. i tried googling but no similar issue .. :s

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. In the Image Details field you are trying to put `<a href="#">image description bla bla</a>`, right?

Comment: yes that's what i'm trying to do but for some reason if i for example put in blabla it will display it. but if i type in <a href="#">image description bla bla</a> it will not display it?

Comment: OH MY GOD... i had it like this: <a href="google.nl"; title="test"></a> i didn't put anything between the >< wow i'm so stupid hahaha thank you man :)